# search_params empty in a PATCH_MANY preprocessor in flask-restless

Tags: python, flask-restless

I have the following HTTP request issued via `PUT`:

```
http://example.com/api/student?q=%7B%22filters%22:%5B%7B%22name%22:%22id%22,%22op%22:%22%3D%3D%22,%22val%22:1%7D%5D,%22disjunction%22:true%7D
```

In which the query string decodes to:

```js
q:{"filters":[{"name":"id","op":"==","val":1}],"disjunction":true}
```

In my flask-restless code, I create the endpoint with these options:

```python
    {
        'model': Student,
        'methods': ['GET', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'POST', 'DELETE'],
        'preprocessors': {
            'POST': [pre_post_student],
            'PATCH_MANY': [pre_patch_many_student]
        },
        'allow_patch_many': True
    },
```

And then I have a preprocessor function defined:

```python
def pre_patch_many_student(search_params=None, data=None, **kw):
    # Handle group management for the given students

    print search_params
```

However, when the function is called for the request above, `search_params` comes up as an empty dict.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When patching, flask-restless doesn't look for the parameters in the url but rather as part of the body of the request.
Thus the body should be:

```
{"q":{<filters and rules>},"field_to_edit":"content",...}
```

This might be too late already but anyways.